# jQuery openmenu on keypress

Tags: jquery, menu

I created a jQuery script which would you require to press numpad0 and it would open up a menu. Pasting `jQuery('.panel_toggle').trigger('click');` works and brings up the menu yet having it in a function doesn't work. Also I must note that the console registers me pressing numpad0 so that works fine to.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".panel_toggle").toggle(function() { 
      jQuery('#panel_stats').stop().animate({'height':'415px'},500)
    },function() {
      jQuery('#panel_stats').stop().animate({'height':'0px'},500)
    });

   jQuery('body, html').live('keypress', openMenu)
});

function openMenu(e){
   console.log(e.keyCode)
   if(e.keyCode == '96')
   {
      e.preventDefault()
      jQuery('.panel_toggle').trigger('click');
    }
}
```

Anyhow I'm very confused.

Comment: Does *clicking* The element work? What does the click event handler on `.panel_toggle` look like?

Comment: Could you post your  html, this code seems fine.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Clicking manually works fine. Menu = "<div class="panel_toggle">MENU</div>"

Comment: @insomiac Its from a MyBB page, I can't post the whole page since it would be massive.